# Ajax google chart onclick

Tags: ajax, charts, onclick

How could the example seen here

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

be modified to load onclick?  I tried doing this very thing with jQuery unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

the google.load() and google.setOnLoadCallback() should be called inside another function

which should be called onclick on div/button where ever you want .

Hope this helps you...